# wso2 governance user group assignment between primary and secondary security domains

Tags: active-directory, registry, wso2

I am running wso2 governance registry with a JDBC backed primary user store and a Active Directory backed secondary store.  What I want to be able to do is create some groups in the primary store (which I have done) and assign users from the secondary store into those roles.

I have done a lot of looking around the wso2 site and google and come up with nothing.  I guess my question is, is it possible and if so how do I do it?

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible. For roles (or groups) created in one userstore, we cannot assign users from another userstore.

However for an internal role, you can assign users from any of the available user stores.